# Android Gitlab CI job failed on “emulator: ERROR: Not enough disk space to run AVD 'testAVD'. Exiting...”

Tags: android, android-studio, continuous-integration, gitlab

Hi currently I am try to run Android instrumental test in Gitlab CI, but i am facing "emulator: ERROR: Not enough disk space to run AVD 'testAVD'. Exiting..." when try to run the emulator, then the CI process will just stuck there.

Gitlab CI result

```
$ echo n | android-sdk-linux/tools/bin/avdmanager create avd -f -n testAVD -k "system-images;android-${ANDROID_COMPILE_SDK};google_apis;x86_64"
Loading local repository...                                                     
[=========                              ] 25% Loading local repository...       
[=========                              ] 25% Fetch remote repository...        
[=========                              ] 25% Fetch remote repository...        
[=========                              ] 25% Fetch remote repository...        
[=======================================] 100% Fetch remote repository...       
Auto-selecting single ABI x86_64
Do you wish to create a custom hardware profile? [no] $ android-sdk-linux/emulator/emulator -avd testAVD -no-audio -no-window &
$ adb wait-for-device
* daemon not running; starting now at tcp:5037
* daemon started successfully
emulator: ERROR: Not enough disk space to run AVD 'testAVD'. Exiting...
```

.gitlab-ci.yml

```
image: openjdk:8-jdk
 variables:
      ANDROID_COMPILE_SDK: "29"
      ANDROID_BUILD_TOOLS: "29.0.3"
      ANDROID_SDK_TOOLS: "4333796"
      CMAKE: "3.10.2.4988404"
    
    before_script:
      - apt-get --quiet update --yes
      - apt-get --quiet install --yes wget tar unzip lib32stdc++6 lib32z1
    
      - wget --quiet --output-document=android-sdk.zip https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sdk-tools-linux-${ANDROID_SDK_TOOLS}.zip
      - unzip -d android-sdk-linux android-sdk.zip
      - echo y | android-sdk-linux/tools/bin/sdkmanager "platforms;android-${ANDROID_COMPILE_SDK}" >/dev/null
      - echo y | android-sdk-linux/tools/bin/sdkmanager "platform-tools" >/dev/null
      - echo y | android-sdk-linux/tools/bin/sdkmanager "build-tools;${ANDROID_BUILD_TOOLS}" >/dev/null
      - echo y | android-sdk-linux/tools/bin/sdkmanager "ndk-bundle" >/dev/null
      - echo y | android-sdk-linux/tools/bin/sdkmanager "cmake;${CMAKE}" >/dev/null
    
      - export ANDROID_HOME=$PWD/android-sdk-linux/
      - export CMAKE_HOME=$PWD/android-sdk-linux/cmake/${CMAKE}/bin/
      - export PATH=$PATH:$PWD/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/:$CMAKE_HOME
    
      - chmod +x ./gradlew
      # temporarily disable checking for EPIPE error and use yes to accept all licenses
      - set +o pipefail
      - yes | android-sdk-linux/tools/bin/sdkmanager --licenses
      - set -o pipefail
    
    stages:
      - test
    
    instrumentationTest:
      stage: test
      script:
        - echo y | android-sdk-linux/tools/bin/sdkmanager  "emulator" >/dev/null
        - echo y | android-sdk-linux/tools/bin/sdkmanager "system-images;android-${ANDROID_COMPILE_SDK};google_apis;x86_64"
        - echo n | android-sdk-linux/tools/bin/avdmanager create avd -f -n testAVD -k "system-images;android-${ANDROID_COMPILE_SDK};google_apis;x86_64"
        - android-sdk-linux/emulator/emulator -avd testAVD -no-audio -no-window &
        - adb wait-for-device
        - adb shell input keyevent 82 &
        - android list target
        - ./gradlew connectedAndroidTest
```

How can i setup the Gitlab to run Android emulator with sufficient disk space?

Answer (score 1):

> How can i setup the Gitlab to run Android emulator with sufficient disk space?

If we are talking about public gitlab.com repositories with their public shared runner then according to [documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/gitlab_com/index.html#linux-shared-runners) we had only 25GB disk space on runner:

> All your CI/CD jobs run on [n1-standard-1](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/machine-types) instances with 3.75GB of RAM, CoreOS and the latest Docker Engine installed. Instances provide 1 vCPU and 25GB of HDD disk space.
>
> The `gitlab-shared-runners-manager-X.gitlab.com` fleet of Runners are dedicated for GitLab projects as well as community forks of them. They use a slightly larger machine type (n1-standard-2) and have a bigger SSD disk size.

— in other words if your project not fork of official GitLab-org repository then runner will have only 25gb space

Other opportunity to increase runner disk space is setup your own runner:

1. [Install GitLab Runner](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/install/)
2. Specify the gitlab url during the Runner setup: https://gitlab.com/ (or you custom gitlab installation host)
3. Go to http://your-repository -> Settings -> CI/CD -> expand `Runners` section and take registration token which you will be asked during setup
4. Start the Runner

Also notice that you can debug runner disk free space by put next command `df -h` after each operation. Like this:

```yaml
instrumentationTest:
  stage: test
  script:
    - df -h 
    - echo y | android-sdk-linux/tools/bin/sdkmanager  "emulator" >/dev/null
    - df -h
    - echo y | android-sdk-linux/tools/bin/sdkmanager "system-images;android-${ANDROID_COMPILE_SDK};google_apis;x86_64"
    - df -h
    - echo n | android-sdk-linux/tools/bin/avdmanager create avd -f -n testAVD -k "system-images;android-${ANDROID_COMPILE_SDK};google_apis;x86_64"
    - df -h
    - android-sdk-linux/emulator/emulator -avd testAVD -no-audio -no-window &
    - df -h
```

Comment: Thanks using custom gitlab runner manage to increase the disk space!